# Two Points with Infinite Distance

Tags: geometry

I have tried looking for an answer to this, but can't seem to find anything.

**Is it possible on a standard Cartesian grid to define two (or more) points with infinite or undefined distance from each other?**

If yes, please provide an example. If no, please explain. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

Being on the standard Cartesian grid would mean the points in hand have real (or, integer) coordinates. However, the distance of points $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ and $(b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n)$ in $n$ dimension can be calculated by $\sqrt{(a_1-b_1)^2+\dots+(a_n-b_n)^2}$, which is a finite real number for any given real coordinates.

---

**Yes.**

We power mathematics, and we **can** define whatever we like, e.g., given the standard Cartesian grid, we *can* introduce (even define with proper terms) an '*endpoint*' at infinity for every line - if we wish, even two for both directions. Then (if we still insist on 'distance' and its nice properties), their distance to ordinary points will be necessarily infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume we have two such points, $A$ and $B$. Then there would be a line $\vec{AB}$ connecting the two points. If this line is not already the $x$ axis, allow us to rotate the Cartesian plane such that it is.

If $A=(x,0)$ what could $B$ possibly equal? We would need to have:

$$|B-A|=(\infty,0)$$

Therefore there could not be any representation of $B$ as a point in the Cartesian plane, since every point has a finite $x$ and $y$ coordinate, and the difference of no two finite numbers is infinite.

Hence we cannot have two points with infinite distance without adding points which we *define* to be "infinitely distant" to the plane; i.e. it is impossible for the standard Cartesian plane.

This Wikipedia article will probably be of interest to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_at_infinity

Answer (score 1):

Tag of "soft question" would match. A kind of paradox, as a plane (or line) as representative of complex or real are unbounded but for two given elements there is always a certain distance, however rhe distance is unlimited.